# What is the difference between "a track" and "a trail" as in "Follow the track/trail to the temple on the top of the mountain"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

It seems that more people say "**Follow the trail to the temple on the top of the mountain**" than "**Follow the track to the temple on the top of the mountain**"?

Is there any difference between "a track" and "a trail" in everyday conversation?

**Are they the same in general?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

Oxford Dictionaries defines a track as *a rough path or road, typically one beaten by use rather than constructed.* 'Trail' can refer to the same kind of path, but 'following a trail' can also refer to following the footprints or clues that an animal or person has left behind, or following a planned walk between official stopping places (a 'nature trail' often has notices telling you what to look out for at different points in your walk).

I'm not sure which kind your climb to the temple is or why you find 'trail' more commonly used.

Comment: Interesting. I won't argue with Oxford on this, but I have never heard "track" used for a "rough path or road".  Instead I always hear it used for constructed paths such as those used for races. What you describe I have always heard called "trail" or "path" for people on foot.